# Emulate signal loss of a pixellated detector in Python?

Tags: discrete-signals, python, matrix

I have a matrix 64x64 where each cell represents the pixel of a pixellated detector.
The  spacial response of this detector decreases by going further from its center (that is, coordinates "31,31" or "32,32"). I have experimental data (10 samples equally distant in the x axis and 10 samples in the y axes) showing that the loss depends on the distance from the center. I have for example the value 100 at the center, the value 70 at coordinates (37, 37), the value 58 at coordinates (43, 43), etc. By plotting this data, it looks like a Gaussian Function.

For post-processing purposes, I would like to compensate each pixel of the matrix by a factor, where the factor is estimated by using the experimental data (20 samples in total) mentioned above.

Examples:

- if at coordinates (16,16) the response resulted to be half compared to the center, I would double the values of that cell
- if at coordinates (10,10) the response is 1/3 compared to the center, I would triplicate the values etc...

Is there a way to do this in Python pixels with scipy.signal or similar or in Matlab?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If all you want to do is compensation, why not create something like CMP_MASK(i,j) = Pmax / p(i,j) where Pmax is the maximum value and p(i,j) is the pixel value at i,j. You then simply multiply the CMP_MASK with the detector's output and compensate its values (presumably for brightness (?)).

Comment: I agree, a mask would do it. But I would like to populate the mask based on the data I have. So rather than using only Pmax, I would like to use all the samples I have in order to replicate more faithfully the behaviour of the sensor (the sample show that is not linear, this is why I want to use the measured samples).